# Can displaying date and time on screen upon TOTP login failure makes system more vulnerable?

Tags: one-time-password, totp, time

We are using TOTP(https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238) for a web application to enhance the security. TOTP works on UTC. if system clock drifts OR NTP is not synced, TOTP generated by application (like MS Authenticator, or Google authenticator or https://totp.danhersam.com/) will not be same as of OTP generated by web-app.
We thought of adding current Date+Time+TZ in error message along with "Invalid TOTP".

So my question is, Information of websites time (lagging or ahead), how attacker can use in any possible way and will make adding date+time+tz information in error message a bad idea ?
Are there any time based attacks?

Comment: The current datetime is probably already being sent in the `Date` HTTP response header, so displaying this in the UI as well would make no difference.

Comment: As an addition: "time based attacks" usually refers to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#In_software) or this is at least what I can only imagine. Because as the answer states, time is a well-known constant of the universe, so an attacker gains nothing from knowing the time explicitly.

Answer (score 18):

It doesn't. The security of TOTP doesn't depend on time being secret. It depends on the *secret* being secret.

I would assume time to be well known and public - best practice is to use NTP, which means that an attacker will know what time is to within a second.

Comment: It does depend on the time of the website being reasonably close to that of generating app. If the website is non-trivially behind and the attacker knows this, it significantly opens the window for an attacker to steal a token, and then replay it later.

Comment: @user1937198 So it's only a potential exploit if the site has another problem that's easily avoided.

Comment: @Barmar Its also only really useful if the site has said other problem. If the site time is properly synced, theres no need to show the time on TOTP failure. Therefore, the assumption is that if you are asking about this risk, you are worried that the site time would be subject to drift.

Comment: @user1937198 Right, didn't read the question fully to see that time drift is an actual concern. But this just makes me think that they're worrying about the wrong thing -- fix the time drift, don't display the time.

Comment: Displaying the time does make it easy to *detect* time drift, then a user can write an angry letter to customer support and (if your organization is functional (which no organizations actually are)) it can be fixed.

Comment: @user253751 Though a better strategy in a functional organization would be to add active monitoring of the time to automatically detect the drift, so the customer does not have to be involved. NTP + alerting on excessive drift should cover all your needs.

Comment: I would also add to this that displaying this information _should_ have little to no value either. It shouldn’t matter for users (because the scenario of their device being sufficiently out of sync for this to be a visible issue can safely be assumed to never happen without them going out of the way to cause it), and it is unlikely to be useful for developers because you should already have that data (and the first thing you should be checking if you hear of issues from users is the time-sync on your server).

Comment: We used to have customers who travelled from London to Barcelona and instead of changing the time zone, they changed the clock. Bit more than “drift”. We displayed server time and client time, so the user had a chance to fix it if the client time was wrong. If my watch says 10:31 and the server says 10:17 then I ask a colleague for the time and then I know to change my clock or to complain about the server.